# How to disable/ignore all key-bindings for a file-formats mode?

Tags: key-bindings

There are some file-type modes I mainly use for syntax highlighting *(some other features may be handy - eldoc for example)*, however when loaded they add key-bindings that override my existing bindings.

Is there a general way to load the associated mode for a file-type **without any of its key-bindings** ?

Comment: Replacing keymaps with new sparse ones doesn't seem to work for every mode, for instance `c-mode` breaks this approach. I have no idea for a robust approach to this at the moment.

Comment: I would suggest putting your own bindings into a special mode map that overrides other modes. The [bind-key](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/2.3/bind-key.el#L40-L43) package provides `bind-key*` which does this.

Comment: This `(add-hook 'some-mode-hook (lambda () (use-local-map nil)))` ?

Comment: @politza - did a quick check on c-mode and this works :) is there a reason this might not be a good general purpose way to disable each modes keymap?

Comment: Not a 100% solution, but binding `define-key` to a function that does nothing should handle most cases.